# Can I refer to an object of another template type inside the class template’s method?

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

My goal is to create a linked list with nodes of different types. For this, I created a node class template as follows:

```
template <class T>
class N_Node
{
public:
    N_Node(T e, N_Node *p = nullptr ,N_Node *n = nullptr);
    void set_previous(N_Node<T> *p);
    void set_next(N_Node<T> *n);
    N_Node get_previous();
    N_Node get_next();

    T element;
    N_Node *prev;
    N_Node *next;
};
```

Now, in the main.cpp, when i try to do the following, it gives me an error saying argument of type `N_Node<int>*` is incompatible with parameter of type `N_Node<char>*`. So, I was wondering if there is any way to specify that the node set as the previous can be of a different type to the current node?

```
N_Node<int> n1(5);
N_Node<char> n3('g');
n3.set_previous(&n1);
```

Comment: sorry but which part needs fixing?

Comment: @nave Look at the current version (in particular Griwes’ changes) and compare it with your original version. To compare the versions you can click on the “edited X secs/minutes ago” link below your post, left next to your user name.

Comment: ok I see it. Thanks for the changes..they make the question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, create a `N_Node_Base` class that omits the `element` member, and inherit from it for `N_Node<T>`.  Most C++ standard library implementations do this to reduce template overhead.

Of course, by doing this you'll lose the ability to traverse the list and access elements because you won't know the type of each element.  You might want to type-erase past a minimal interface for `T` using e.g. `boost::any`, but you'll have to say more about why you want to do this.

Comment: well, the objective was to create a heterogenous list that dynamically resizes.

Comment: Having a heterogeneous list makes sense in managed / scripting languages, where everything is an object (or can be boxed into an object).  In C++ there isn't a single base `object` type (although plenty of frameworks offer one) and similarly for boxing.  You need to consider what you want to *do with* the elements of the list.